# Get my personal data contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I need to get my personal contact. In android 4.0 and higher we have a my data contact. I've tried with `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME` but i got all my contacts without my data contact. Any idea how to get it?

This is my code:

```
public String getMyName(ContentResolver resolver){

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] columns = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    Cursor people = resolver.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
    try {
        int nameIndex = people.getColumnIndex(columns[0]);
        int numberIndex = people.getColumnIndex(columns[1]);

        people.moveToFirst();
        do{
            Log.d("Contact result", "Contact name: " + people.getString(nameIndex) + " contact phone: " + people.getString(numberIndex));
        } while (people.moveToNext());
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.d("Exception", "Null pointer on get personal data");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've found the library for it.

https://gist.github.com/remelpugh/4072663

It helps to get my personal data.